# Automatically close tk ENTRY window after clicking submit button

Tags: tkinter, python-3.5

I am creating a sign-out program in python 3.5. I have been looking around and have seen how to close a window using a "close/exit/quit" button. What I want to do is automatically close the window after they click the "submit" button to send the text in the ENTRY box to a file. I have tried to add the .destroy() in different way in the write_to_file, but i keep getting an error saying it is not defined. I created a def for it like some examples i have seen but I don't know how to have write_to_file call it. The program writes what is in the Entry box correctly to the file. Any help would be appreciated.

```
class Writefiles:

    def __init__(self):
        win3 = Tk()
        win3.title('Signature')
        win3['bg'] = 'blue'
        win3.geometry('300x200')
        center(win3)

        self.VarEnt = StringVar()

        self.lab = Label(win3, text = "Name")
        self.lab.grid(padx = 10, pady = 10)

        self.ent = Entry(win3, textvariable = self.VarEnt, bd = 5, width = 45)
        self.ent.focus()
        self.ent.grid(padx = 10, pady = 10)

        self.btn = Button(win3, text = 'Submit', width = 10, height = 2, background = 'gold', command = self.write_to_file)
        self.btn.grid(padx = 10, pady = 10)


    def write_to_file(self):

        date = datetime.now().strftime('   %Y-%m-%d  %H:%M:%S') 

        with open('sig.txt', 'a') as f:
            f.write(self.ent.get() + date + '\n')
            f.close()


    def close_win(self):        # close tkinter window
        self.ent.destroy()
```

Comment: Closing a window is indeed done by calling `destroy()` on that window. If you need help with any errors, you're going to have to post those errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to make win3 global and then when I added win3.destroy() to the write_to_file so it will close the window after the button is clicked. If you don't make it global you will get a NameError: 'win3' is not defined.

I removed the def close_win(self): section.

The corrected code:

```
class Writefiles:

def __init__(self):
    self.win3 = Tk()
    self.win3.title('Signature')
    self.win3['bg'] = 'blue'
    self.win3.geometry('300x200')
    center(self.win3)

    self.VarEnt = StringVar()

    self.lab = Label(self.win3, text = "Name")
    self.lab.grid(padx = 10, pady = 10)

    self.ent = Entry(self.win3, textvariable = self.VarEnt, bd = 5, width = 45)
    self.ent.focus()
    self.ent.grid(padx = 10, pady = 10)

    self.btn = Button(self.win3, text = 'Submit', width = 10, height = 2, background = 'gold', command = self.write_to_file)
    self.btn.grid(padx = 10, pady = 10)


def write_to_file(self):

    date = datetime.now().strftime('   %Y-%m-%d  %H:%M:%S')

    with open('sig.txt', 'a') as f:
        f.write(self.ent.get() + date + '\n')
        f.close()

    self.win3.destroy()   # to close window after files is written
```

**EDIT** After seeing @gms comment, I removed the `global` and added `self.` to the win3 entries. I edited the above code to show the corrections.

Answer (score 0):

You have to destroy the win3 window and not the entry. Just write 
win3.destroy() at the end of def write_to_file(self).

You can destroy windows (like the root window or a Toplevel window that is a child of the root window) and not the widgets of the window. Destroying the root window you destroy all windows and exit the program.

At the def close_win(self) you are trying to destroy the ent Entry and not its parent window win3

Comment: When I added it to the end of the def, I get the NameError: 'win3' is not defined. Do I need to add something to it so it will look for it in the __init__ section? I tried adding self but I then get a AttributeError: 'Writefiles' object has no attribute 'win3'.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I didn't see the question...
You use win3=Tk() and you refer to it as win3. You must use self.win3 inside the definition of the class. So change all win3 inside the class to self.win3. Also I am not sure if you need the global win3 at all

Comment: It works both ways but I now understand that using 'self' is the python way, so I added it to all the win3 in the class and removed the global. Thanks

Comment: You can't be able to access a variable without self. in other methods of the class or outside of the class. Without self in a variable inside a class  you have a local variable. Its like a local variable of a function: You can access it outside the  function only if you make it global. That's why you set the self in front of a variable inside the class.